# how to add second click to the button plain javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

Can anyone tell me how to add another click to the button to sort the elements from 5 to 0?

first click: sort from 0 to 5
second click: sort from 5 to 0
third click: sort from 0 to 5
fourth click sort from 5 to 0
etc etc

```js
var card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
var container = document.querySelector(".container");


function getPrice(node) {
  return node.getAttribute('data-price');
}

function compareCards(a, b) {
  return getPrice(a) > getPrice(b);
}

function append(node) {
  container.appendChild(node);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  container.innerHTML = ''; [...card].sort(compareCards).forEach(append);
});
```

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000;
}

.red{
  background: red;
}

.blue{
  background: blue;
}

.pink{
  background: pink;
}

.green{
  background: green;
}

.purple{
  background: purple;
}

.yellow{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card purple" data-price=4>4</div>
  <div class="card pink" data-price=2>2</div>
  <div class="card red" data-price=0>0</div>
  <div class="card green" data-price=3>3</div>
  <div class="card yellow" data-price=5>5</div>
  <div class="card blue" data-price=1>1</div>
</div>

<button class="btn">click to sort</button>
```

Comment: when it clicks and the mode is changed definitely user also need the feeling. I think you better add a class when it is ascending order and descending order.  $("btn .asc").click(function(){
   //sort ASC order
}); $("btn .desc").click(function(){
   //sort DESC order
}); like class in this page vote-up-off
vote-down-off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep trace of your button state with a variable *(Here `ascOrder`)* and use `Array#reverse()` half of the times :

```js
var card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var ascOrder = true;

function getPrice(node) {
  return node.getAttribute('data-price');
}

function compareCards(a, b) {
  return getPrice(a) > getPrice(b);
}

function append(node) {
  container.appendChild(node);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(ascOrder){
    ascOrder = false;
    container.innerHTML = ''; [...card].sort(compareCards).forEach(append);
  }else{
    ascOrder = true;
    container.innerHTML = ''; [...card].sort(compareCards).reverse().forEach(append);
  }
  
});
```

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000;
}

.red{
  background: red;
}

.blue{
  background: blue;
}

.pink{
  background: pink;
}

.green{
  background: green;
}

.purple{
  background: purple;
}

.yellow{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card purple" data-price=4>4</div>
  <div class="card pink" data-price=2>2</div>
  <div class="card red" data-price=0>0</div>
  <div class="card green" data-price=3>3</div>
  <div class="card yellow" data-price=5>5</div>
  <div class="card blue" data-price=1>1</div>
</div>

<button class="btn">click to sort</button>
```

Comment: thank you very much. clear and simple. have a nice evening my friend:)

Answer (score 0):

- Use a variable to change your sort direction.
- According to that flag, sort your array.

## Look at this code snippet.

```js
var card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn')
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var asc = false;

function getPrice(node) {
  return node.getAttribute('data-price');
}

function compareCards(a, b, asc) {
  if (asc) {
    return getPrice(a) > getPrice(b);
  }
  
  return getPrice(a) < getPrice(b);
}

function append(node) {
  container.appendChild(node);
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  asc = !asc;
  container.innerHTML = ''; [...card].sort(function(a, b) {
    return compareCards(a, b, asc);
  }).forEach(append);
});
```

```css
body{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.card{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000;
}

.red{
  background: red;
}

.blue{
  background: blue;
}

.pink{
  background: pink;
}

.green{
  background: green;
}

.purple{
  background: purple;
}

.yellow{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card purple" data-price=4>4</div>
  <div class="card pink" data-price=2>2</div>
  <div class="card red" data-price=0>0</div>
  <div class="card green" data-price=3>3</div>
  <div class="card yellow" data-price=5>5</div>
  <div class="card blue" data-price=1>1</div>
</div>

<button class="btn">click to sort</button>
```